# monitoring wallets transactions

Tags: erc-20, web3.py

I am kinda lost in web3.py documents.

I want to track a given wallet address for any SWAP of any erc20 tokens.

I wrote the code to track it on a specific smart contract but cannot find the solution to work it generally for any trade on that wallet.

is this even possible?

Comment: Did you try using `Transfer` events? What did you try? Can you share the code?

Comment: I use Swap event filter to read from a token's uniswap pair address for a wallet address. I dunno how to start monitoring a wallet for ANY token swap. like should I read every block and find for a tx for that wallet address?

Comment: I'm not a python developer, did you try using filters https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/filters.html?